# Python Selenium Detach Option Not Working

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to write a Python script using Selenium and Chrome where Selenium won't close the Chrome browser when the script finishes. From doing a bunch of googling, it looks like the standard solution is to use the detach option. But when I run the following script:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options() 
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
```

It opens up Chrome, goes to Google's homepage, and  then closes the browser. It's not throwing any errors.

Any idea why it's not working? I'm using the latest version of Google Chrome on Windows 10, and I've got the latest version of the selenium module installed. I couldn't find anything online that said the experimental detach option no longer existed. And I double checked the [API](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver), and it looks like it's the right syntax.

Comment: Where is driver path in your code ?

Comment: have you tried setting `chrome_options=chrome_options`, rather than `options=chrome_options`?

Comment: If you don't specify the driver path, it uses a default path -- and it was finding the driver just fine. I also tried adding the driver name, and I got the same results

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention: I tried both chrome_options as well as options. Same result.

Comment: @AndersSchneiderman u want the browser to not be closed when your script is done, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code worked perfectly for me using : `selenium-wire` , hope it works for you

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(),options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
```

Answer (score 1):

I discovered another way to go: start Chrome in remote debugging mode, then connect to it. That way, not only does the browser stay open, but you can also use your existing Chrome profile so you can take advantage of any sites your cookies allow you to access without having to log in every time you run the script.

Here's what you need to do if you're on Windows 10:

1. Start Google Chrome up remotely, pointed towards [your existing user profile](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/HEAD/docs/user_data_dir.md) and the port you want to use:

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application"
chrome.exe -remote-debugging-port=9014 --user-data-dir="%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data"
```

2. In your python script, connect to the  local port that this version of Chrome is running on:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "localhost:9014")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

driver.get("https://github.com/")
```

Comment: a great alternative, but i suggest u check this: https://pypi.org/project/selenium-wire/ for future projects with selenium

Answer (score 0):

**This code works well now:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

r_options = Options()
r_options.add_experimental_option('detach', True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=r_options)
```

Comment: The code you submitted is the same as in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use **Pycharm**? in windows cmd commandline terminal no this problem.

```
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
# remember don't call driver.quit()
```

With Pycharm, Browser closes 2-5 seconds after the script ends. but it is not due to the detach option.

if you set detach True and not call driver.quit(), the browser will not closed by chromedriver.

If it also closed, try this option:

```
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
```

This option will disable the info in the script terminal like:

> DevTools listening on
> ws://127.0.0.1:9512/devtools/browser/ed13e40d-2fa3-47ea-ae63-a2975f282b85

I guess the Browser's stdout may redirect to our script's terminal, if our script ends，Pycharm close the terminal, so the browser output will fail, and it killed itself.(only guess, need confirm)

[image]